# Why does this async js function not print done

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Consider the following script:

```js
async function fn() {
    await new Promise(() => { console.log("promise"); });
    console.log("done");
}
fn();
```

The output is

```
promise
```

If I don't await the promise then the result differs.

```js
async function fn() {
    new Promise(() => { console.log("promise"); });
    console.log("done");
}
fn();
```

The output now is more along the expected lines.

```
promise
done
```

I am assuming this is coming from wrong usage of the language somehow but I would like to know the reason for this difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your promise executor is not calling the `resolve` function that you're expected to call when a promise you create with [`new Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise) should be resolved.

In other words, your

```
async function fn() {
    await new Promise(() => { console.log("promise"); });
    console.log("done");
}
fn();
```

should be

```
async function fn() {
    await new Promise((resolve) => { console.log("promise"); resolve(); });
    console.log("done");
}
fn();
```

if you ever expect it to finish; if you don't call `resolve`, the runtime can't know when the promise has finished (and since the idea of `new Promise` is to wrap callback-based APIs, it's not enough to just consider the executor function returning having resolved the promise).

If you don't `await` for the promise, it will run (since promises start running immediately, not only when awaited), but it too will have never actually resolved.

Comment: So iiuc in the first case (when resolve is not invoked and we do an `await`) the program is basically suspended at that point for a promise that is never settled?

Comment: Well, the execution of that function `fn` is suspended (since it itself is `async`). If you add `console.log("ok!")` after the `fn()` invocation, you'll see that it will run (since you're not `await fn()`ing).

Answer (score -1):

If you're only seeing "promise" in the output and not "done," it could be due to a couple of reasons:

1. Asynchronous Nature: The await keyword is used to wait for the Promise to resolve before moving on to the next line of code. However, if there is an unhandled error in the Promise or if the Promise never resolves, it can cause the subsequent code (including console.log("done");) not to be executed.
2. Program Termination: If the environment where you are running this code terminates before the Promise has a chance to resolve, you might not see the "done" message.